# Removing white spaces within json value

Tags: java, json

I have a string which stores webservice response as below.  In this string I want to remove the whitespace next to the double quotes(opening & closing" using java.

```
String WebserviceResponse;

    {
        "assessmentID": 289,
        "assesmentName": " OneCert ",
        "accountName": " spadmin ",
        "assetName": " OneCert ",
        "applicationName": " OneCert ",
        "accountType": " LocalAccount ",
        "environment": " Test "
    },
    {
        "assessmentID": 289,
        "assesmentName": "OneCert ",
        "accountName": "9000032",
        "assetName": "OneCert",
        "applicationName": "OneCert ",
        "accountType": "zone2.scbdev.net",
        "environment": "Test"
    }
```

I tried the below code to remove space next to double quotes
String FormattedResponse= WebserviceResponse.replaceAll( "\s","" );

but it removes all the spaces.  Can you please help me on this.

Comment: If you just want to remove whitespace in a JSON _value_ you need to know what part of defines a value (and maybe even which value). Thus you need to first _parse_ the JSON string to an actual object, identify and modify the value you want and reserialize the object to a JSON string. - Don't try with regular expressions as this is a receipe for disaster: JSON is not a regular language and thus regular expressions are not a good fit.

Comment: Parse the JSON, update the value, re-generate the JSON.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to parse the JSON, you can use this regex: `(?>\\S)(\\s)(?>\")` [updated below] and replace the matches with `""` (empty string).

Breaking this up:

`(?>\\S)` non-capturing group, looking for anything that is NOT a whitespace

`(\\s)` a capturing group looking for a whitespace

`(?>\")` a non-capturing group, looking for `"` (quotes)

You'll have whitespaces matches. Then is just `replaceAll()` with `""` (empty string).

Result here: [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/zZrIkS/1)

### UPDATE

I did some tests and I had some issues with non-capturing group and java. It may be better to use lookahead/lookbehind. I'm updating the answer and posting an example here.

This is the lookahead/lookbehind version of the regex: `(?<=\")(\\s)(?=\\w)|(?<=\\w)(\\s)(?=\")`. [Regex101](https://regex101.com/r/kAfUea/1)

## Example in Java

```
" \" assesmentName\": \" OneCert \"".replaceAll("(?<=\")(\\s)(?=\\w)|(?<=\\w)(\\s)(?=\")", "")
```

resulting in:

```java
"assesmentName": "OneCert"
```

### Breaking up

`(?<=\")(\\s)(?=\\w)` look for quote, space, word (letter or number); or

`(?<=\\w)(\\s)(?=\")` look for a word (letter or number), space, quote

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to escape the backslashes. Updated.

Answer (score 1):

**Please note:** The following example probably only works on basic JSON strings. For better results you should use some [lib](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) to decode, filter and encode String again.

You could use some regexp on the string, something like this:

Thanks to: https://regex101.com/r/FVPbD0/4

```
"([^"]+)":\s*"\s*([^"]+)\s*"
```

- Roughly, this extracts the key and value without spaces into groups
- and replaces them without the spaces

Java code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

final String regex = "\"([^\"]+)\":\\s*\"\\s*([^\"]+)\\s*\"";
final String string = " {\n"
     + "        \"assessmentID\": 289,\n"
     + "        \"assesmentName\": \" OneCert \",\n"
     + "        \"accountName\": \" spadmin \",\n"
     + "        \"assetName\": \" OneCert \",\n"
     + "        \"applicationName\": \" OneCert \",\n"
     + "        \"accountType\": \" LocalAccount \",\n"
     + "        \"environment\": \" Test \"\n"
     + "    },\n"
     + "    {\n"
     + "        \"assessmentID\": 289,\n"
     + "        \"assesmentName\": \"OneCert \",\n"
     + "        \"accountName\": \"9000032\",\n"
     + "        \"assetName\": \"OneCert\",\n"
     + "        \"applicationName\": \"OneCert \",\n"
     + "        \"accountType\": \"zone2.scbdev.net\",\n"
     + "        \"environment\": \"Test\"\n"
     + "    }";
final String subst = "\"$1\": \"$2\"";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.MULTILINE);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

// The substituted value will be contained in the result variable
final String result = matcher.replaceAll(subst);

System.out.println("Substitution result: " + result);
```